# Set options after angular modal opened

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

How can I set options on an angularUi Modal after it is opened?

I create my modal with

```
var popup = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'parts/payments/views/ConfirmPayoutModal.html',
    controller: 'PayoutCtrl',
    windowClass: 'payout-modal',
});
```

and I can access it in my 'PayoutCtrl' via a $modalInstance, for example

```
$modalInstance.close();
```

But how can I set options for the modal when something happens, after it is opened?

```
backdrop: 'static',
keyboard: false
```

Comment: You can add this attribute using your modal selector ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.
Html code

```
<div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" ng-hide="ispromiseprogress==true" class="close" ng-click="cancel()" aria-hidden="true"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"
                                                                                      style="color:black"></i></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
</div>
$scope.ispromiseprogress=false;
     $scope.open = function () {
                modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'login.html',
                    windowClass: 'app-modal-window',
                    backdrop: false,
                    keyboard: false,
                    modalFade: true,
                    scope: $scope,
                    controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, $http) {
                        $scope.getData=function(){
$scope.ispromiseprogress=true;
 $http.get(myurl)
            .success(function(data){
$scope.ispromiseprogress=false;
                $scope.login={};
                $scope.login.status=false;
            })
            .error(function(data){
$scope.ispromiseprogress=false;
                window.location="/logout"
            })
}
                        $scope.cancel = function () {
                            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                        };
                    }

                })
            }
```

Comment: Yes, then I can dismiss - I can allready do that. I want to set some options

Comment: what type of options

Comment: I need to set "backdrop: 'static' and "keyboard: false" when something happens in the modal

Comment: what you mean by something mean.did mean when user interact with modal.

Comment: I have a button in the modal, that activates a function. While that function is running/havent returned its promise, I don't want the user to be able to leave the modal

Comment: I have made some change in solution.

Comment: You can still tap escape or click the background at any time to close the modal while the action is being performed.  That's specifically what this questions was asking to prevent.